# Is there a meaning behind 'mater' and 'pater' beyond mother and father?

Tags: etymology, gender

I ask because i vaguely remember pater, the latin root for father, also having the meaning 'to protect' or 'to lead'? A fairly thorough google search has yet to substantiate that so I might have just imagined it.

Still, it isn't without precedent, at least with older languages. For example, the biblical hebrew word for woman, 'nekeva' means 'to be penetrated,' in a metonym.

Offtopic, but am also curious what other languages might have metonyms for certain gender identities.

Comment: I'll leave this question to some of the actual linguistics experts on this site, but you're almost certainly recalling something about the conjectured PIE (=Proto-Indo-European) link between *ph₂tḗr (->pater, father) and [*peh₂-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/peh%E2%82%82-) ("protect, shepherd," cf. pāscō, ποιμήν). This is a PIE thing, though, not Latin.